# nginx speed control based on cookies [or any other variable I can set on the fly]?

Tags: performance, nginx, controls

I have this config in my Nginx server:

```
limit_rate 500k;
location ~ \.mp4$ {
    mp4;
    limit_rate_after 4m;
    limit_rate 90k;
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    limit_conn addr 2;
}
```

I want the speed and the burst controlled on the fly by a mean of cookies (can't alter URL as I need it in certain length/structure)

Is there a way to put something like this?

```
if($cookie_burst){
    limit_rate_after {$cookie_burst}m;//how can I use cookie value here along with m[Megabytes]?
}
```

Edit: I cahnged the URL requesting the mp4 file, adding a burst argument, now using $arg_burst in Nginx config file.

However, I can test for $arg_burst but I can't use it in a line like this:

This works:

```
if ($arg_burst = "1m"){
   limit_rate_after 1m;
}
```

This doesn't :( :

```
if ($arg_burst != ""){
   limit_rate_after $arg_burst;
}
```

Any workaround to put whatever value I want there, on the fly?

Comment: Could you define a number of levels/steps and use `if` statements to control things that way? I know it's not optimal, but it should work at a simple level. Otherwise, maybe create a script to define a large number of if/levels and import that file?